# Is "I would like to know" informal?

Tags: formality

I'm sending an e-mail to schedule my internship.
Is this sentence, "I would like to know if I can cover up Thursday's by working extra hours on other days." sounds informal?

Is there a better way to ask this kind of question in a nicer and formal way?

Thanks!

Comment: Define "*informal*". Informal to whom, in what context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks formal enough; the context needs some clarification. Remember, the magic word never fails:

> I would like to know if I can cover up Thursday's hours by working extra hours on other days, please.

And turning it into a question makes it even better:

> Would you please let me know if I can cover up Thursday's hours by working extra hours on other days?

Then, it's formal enough for your internship.

Comment: Who downvoted this? This is a right answer.

Answer (score 2):

It's not too informal for an email, but *make up* may sound more natural than *cover up*, since *make up* suggests *restore* while *cover up* suggests *conceal*.

Comment: I agree with you on that make up sounds more natural, great point! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

"I would like to know if/whether..." sounds kind of awkward and unnatural in this particular context.

Instead, I'd suggest being more direct, yet polite, and say:

> *May I make up Thursday's hours by working extra hours on other days?*